# How to implement a simple master-detail in a JFace WizardPage

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, master-detail

I want to implement a simple master-detail scenario in Jface WizardPage:
The WizardPage will have one table with some names, upon selecting a row in the table the bottom part of the WizardPage containing texts/labels gets updated with the details corresponding to the selection in the table.

I searched internet and found only examples that run as SWT application:
http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet010MasterDetail.java?view=markup

```
1   /*******************************************************************************
2    * Copyright (c) 2007, 2009 Brad Reynolds and others.
3    * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
4    * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
5    * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
6    * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
7    *
8    * Contributors:
9    *     Brad Reynolds - initial API and implementation
10   *     Matthew Hall - bug 260329
11   ******************************************************************************/
12  
13  package org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding.snippets;
14  
15  import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
16  import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
17  
18  import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
19  import org.eclipse.core.databinding.UpdateValueStrategy;
20  import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.BeansObservables;
21  import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm;
22  import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.IObservableValue;
23  import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.SWTObservables;
24  import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.ViewersObservables;
25  import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
26  import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ListViewer;
27  import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
28  import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
29  import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
30  import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
31  import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
32  
33  /**
34   * Snippet that displays a simple master detail use case. A list of persons is
35   * displayed in a list and upon selection the name of the selected person will
36   * be displayed in a Text widget.
37   */
38  public class Snippet010MasterDetail {
39          public static void main(String[] args) {
40                  final Display display = new Display();
41                  Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display), new Runnable() {
42                          public void run() {
43                                  Shell shell = new Shell(display);
44                                  shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
45  
46                                  Person[] persons = new Person[] { new Person("Me"),
47                                                  new Person("Myself"), new Person("I") };
48  
49                                  ListViewer viewer = new ListViewer(shell);
50                                  viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
51                                  viewer.setInput(persons);
52  
53                                  Text name = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
54  
55                                  // 1. Observe changes in selection.
56                                  IObservableValue selection = ViewersObservables
57                                                  .observeSingleSelection(viewer);
58  
59                                  // 2. Observe the name property of the current selection.
60                                  IObservableValue detailObservable = BeansObservables
61                                                  .observeDetailValue(selection, "name", String.class);
62  
63                                  // 3. Bind the Text widget to the name detail (selection's
64                                  // name).
65                                  new DataBindingContext().bindValue(SWTObservables.observeText(
66                                                  name, SWT.None), detailObservable,
67                                                  new UpdateValueStrategy(false,
68                                                                  UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_NEVER), null);
69  
70                                  shell.open();
71                                  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
72                                          if (!display.readAndDispatch())
73                                                  display.sleep();
74                                  }
75                          }
76                  });
77                  display.dispose();
78          }
79  
80          public static class Person {
81                  private String name;
82                  private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
83  
84                  Person(String name) {
85                          this.name = name;
86                  }
87  
88                  public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
89                          changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
90                  }
91                  
92                  public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
93                          changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
94                  }
95                  
96                  /**
97                   * @return Returns the name.
98                   */
99                  public String getName() {
100                         return name;
101                 }
102 
103                 public String toString() {
104                         return name;
105                 }
106         }
107 }
```

How to integrate this in a JFace Wizard?
And this wizard should run as a Eclipse plugin

Comment: I tried to integrate the above example in the createControl() method of the WizardPage. But its not working, I am not sure of where to create the Display and Shell objects in JFace Wizard scenario (I am new to SWT/JFace stuff). I did not understand how and where I should  "dispose" appropriate objects. Are Display and Shell internally created and handled in JFace Wizard? I tried Display.getDefault() and getShell() inside createControl() method, but its a not the correct place to do. Still searching for examples that show how to integrate this in Jface wizard. Any help is appreciable!

Comment: Well I also tried `addSelectionChangedListener` on the master table but this updates the details table for the first time and no later selection changes updates the details table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(shell, new MyWizard());
    wizardDialog.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class MyWizard extends Wizard
{
    protected MyWizardPage one;

    public MyWizard()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        one = new MyWizardPage("Page One");
        addPage(one);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        return false;
    }

}

private static class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage
{
    protected MyWizardPage(String pageName) {
        super(pageName);
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite comp)
    {
        Composite container = new Composite(comp, SWT.NULL);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, true);
        container.setLayout(layout);

        final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);

        // First column is for the name
        TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn("Name", 100, 0, viewer);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                {
                    return ((Person)element).getName();
                }
                return "";
            }
        });

        // First column is for the location
        TableViewerColumn col2 = createTableViewerColumn("Location", 100, 1, viewer);
        col2.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                {
                    return ((Person)element).getLocation();
                }
                return "";
            }
        });

        final Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        data.horizontalSpan = 2;
        table.setLayoutData(data);

        /* Add listener to listen for selection change */
        final Text name = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
        name.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        final Text location = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
        location.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent arg0) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
                Person person = (Person) selection.getFirstElement();

                name.setText(person.getName());
                location.setText(person.getLocation());
            }
        });

        viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        final Person[] persons = new Person[] { new Person("Baz", "Loc"),
                new Person("BazBaz", "LocLoc"), new Person("BazBazBaz", "LocLocLoc") };

        viewer.setInput(persons);

        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(false);
    }
}

private static TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound, final int colNumber, TableViewer viewer) {
    final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText(title);
    column.setWidth(bound);
    column.setResizable(true);
    column.setMoveable(false);

    return viewerColumn;
}

public static class Person {
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Person(String name, String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + location;
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the text fields are filled with the content of the table. I'm sure you are able to use this code snippet for your purpose.